# Gray box around figure with a separate gray box around caption

Tags: floats, captions, framed

My university requires that all figures in a thesis follow this pattern:

[image: desired result]

I'm very new to LaTeX, so far my best attempt has been this:

```
\begin{SCfigure}
    \colorbox{darkgray}{
         \begin{minipage}{14cm}
              \centering
              \includegraphics{inductor.jpg}
         \end{minipage}
    }
    \caption{caption caption}
\end{SCfigure}
```

and the result is here: [image: result so far]

My figure is not centered and the caption is off the page.

Trying to create another minipage around caption does not work because the colored box somehow appears in between the figure and caption.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "the image `http://th.upic.me/i/dy/21untitled-1.jpg` cannot be displayed because it contains errors"

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please make sure that all images are uploaded using the official stackexchange interface, i.e. the image icon on top of the text field (shortcut: CTRL+G). This ensures that all images are always accessible and do not expire. (As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.)

Comment: @wh1t3 images are fixed now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All problems are not resolved. You need to create a macro to automate all the  little jobs and I have not used Arial and 8pt.
It will be fine to cretae a macro with argument the caption and the picture. I placed a `minipage` inside a `minipage` to get margins around the caption. I think there is perhaps a better way to this. I used a box to get the height of the picture, I don't know if  it's possible to avoid this.

update 4: I added a macro like Herbert and I adapted the code to odd and even pages but you need to make some calculations to replace `\hspace*{-6em}` and `\hspace*{-4em}` by something like `\hspace*{\dimexpr -\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax}` (Herbert's code). I don't know exactly what are the macros for a `twoside` document to calculate the left and right margin.
I corrected 2 bugs. I added some extra space around the picture

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{fourier,xcolor,graphicx} 
\usepackage[font={sf}]{caption} 
 \usepackage{ifthen,changepage,lipsum}

\newsavebox{\mybox}      

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{period-newline}{.\newline\newline}
\captionsetup{aboveskip=3pt,singlelinecheck=false,
              labelsep=period-newline,labelfont={small,bf}} 
\newcommand\Image[4][width=\textwidth]{%
\savebox{\mybox}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}} 
\fboxsep=0pt 
\checkoddpage  
\ifthenelse{\boolean{oddpage}}{%   
\hspace*{-25mm}  
\hbox{\colorbox{black!10}{\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr \ht\mybox+4mm}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{38mm}\center
 \begin{minipage}[b]{34mm}
   \caption[courte]{#3}
    \label{#4} 
 \end{minipage}%
\end{minipage}}%
\hspace*{2mm}
\colorbox{black!25}{%
\begin{minipage}[b]{145mm}\center
    \vspace*{2mm} 
\colorbox{white}{\usebox\mybox}%
  \vspace*{2mm}  
\end{minipage}}}%     
}{%   
  \hspace*{-40mm}%    
\hbox{\colorbox{black!25}{%
\begin{minipage}[b]{145mm}\center
  \vspace*{2mm}
\colorbox{white}{\usebox\mybox}%
 \vspace*{2mm}  
\end{minipage}}% 
\hspace*{2mm}  
\colorbox{black!10}{\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr \ht\mybox+4mm}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{38mm}\center
 \begin{minipage}[b]{34mm}
   \caption[courte]{#3}
    \label{#4}  
 \end{minipage}%
\end{minipage}}}% 
}   
}
\begin{document} 


\section {Figures/Capturing}

Place Tables/Figures/lmages in text as close to the reterence as possible. (see Figure 1). The table, frgure or image has to put in the area which is width 14.5 cm., filled with 70\% black colm. You should leave 2 mm. tram margin. In a side oox (width 3.8 cm., filled with 15\% Black), a short caption could be in the bottom. 

\begin{figure}[h!]               
 \Image[width=8cm]{elephant.pdf}{Long texte de légende avec quelques explications sur une figure importante}{elephant}  
\end{figure} 

ln tables, pictures, images or captures. use 10pt Arial regular to describe. Each f<gure (group) must include a caption set in 8-points Arial regular. The caption is to be on left or right depends on odd or even page. Figure numbering and referencing should be done sequentially, e.g. Figure. 1, Figure. 2, Table 1., Table 2 .. etc. for single figure and Figure l(a), Figure 1(b)., etc., for figures with multiple parts.    

\lipsum [1]
\section {Figures/Capturing}

\begin{figure}[h!]              
 \Image[width=8cm]{elephant.pdf}{Long texte de légende avec quelques explications sur une figure importante}{elephant bis}  
\end{figure} 
Compare with  the first picture \ref{elephant}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Pete Sorry I have not enough time to cretae a macro but an expert on this site will complete this beginning of solution.

Comment: I tried your macro on twoside documenclass and it's not centered. Also, the caption has to be on the inside margin. Help a little bit more please!

Comment: I forgot this condition. You need to adapt my code for the exact calculation of the left margin.

Comment: I prefer the method `tabularx` of Herbert but I can't adapt some little things like `\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator` to get exactly the same picture.

Comment: Yes you can use `\hspace*{-2.5cm}` and `\hspace*{-1.5cm}`  but a better approach is to make calculations like Herbert but you have to know all the parameters of the layout

Comment: Is it possible to leave a bit of vertical space around the picture?

Comment: Yes but where exactly ? around the two rectangle or around only the picture ? I will modify my answer

Comment: Around the picture so that the inside border of both the picture and caption has the same width. Tell me if this is unclear.

Comment: I tried to label the figure by using `\label{}` inside the figure environment but the output showed **Figure ??** How can I properly label figure in this case?

Comment: @Pete you needed to modify the macro `\Image`, see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

It needs two LaTeX runs to get the left/right pages correct

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,tabularx,ifthen} 
\usepackage{lipsum}     
\newcounter{ImageCounter}
\usepackage[font={small,sf},skip=-\normalbaselineskip]{caption}     
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}
\newcommand\Image[3][width=\textwidth]{%
 \stepcounter{ImageCounter}\label{SpecialImage-\theImageCounter}%
 \ifthenelse{\isodd{\pageref{SpecialImage-\theImageCounter}}}%
  {\hspace*{-1cm}%\dimexpr -\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax}%
   \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr \marginparwidth+\marginparsep+\textwidth+1cm\relax}%
     {@{}>{\columncolor{black!30}\centering} X @{\kern3pt} l 
         >{\columncolor{black!15}}b{1.3\marginparwidth} @{}}
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2} & & \caption{#3} 
   \end{tabularx}}%
  {\hspace*{\dimexpr -\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax}%
   \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr \marginparwidth+\marginparsep+\textwidth+1cm\relax}%
     {@{}>{\columncolor{black!15}}b{1.3\marginparwidth} @{\kern3pt} l 
         >{\columncolor{black!30}\centering} X @{}}
   \caption{#3}  & & \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
   \end{tabularx}}%
}
\begin{document} 

\section {Figures/Capturing}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\Image[width=8cm,height=6cm]{tiger}{Some nonsense text for the also superfluos 
           caption of the tiger for the also superfluos caption of the tiger}  
\end{figure} 

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\Image[width=8cm,height=6cm]{tiger}{Some nonsense text for the also superfluos 
           caption of the tiger for the also superfluos caption of the tiger}  
\end{figure} 

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why all these calculations ? The specifications are 14.5 cm for the picture, 38 mm for the caption and 2mm for the interspace, but good idea for `talularx`, no need to calculate the height of the boxes.

Comment: I have two problems with your code. There is a blank space at the top of the columns and the caption is not at the bottom of the first column.

Comment: +1 Can this be adapted to behave differently on odd and even pages (as requested by the OP)

Comment: @Herbert I tried your code on a twoside document and it's not centered. The caption also needs to be on the inside margin as well. Please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to use `\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator` with your method. I think you chose the best method with `tabularx`.

Comment: @Pete: see edited answer. If you want to have the caption on the other side then simply change the order of the arguments of `\ifthenelse`

Comment: It works great. But the figure is not centered (caption went off page). Maybe is it because my layout is like this?
`\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm, left=3.17cm, right=2.54cm]{geometry}`
It's the page margin requirements, sorry I didn't include in the beginning.

Comment: Also, may I ask what's the importance of `\stepcounter` in this situation?

Comment: Inside TeX you do not really know what's the number of the page. It is set when the page is completely typeset, but then it is too late to check its value. With my own counter and increasing it by `\stepnumber` for every new image I can define a label and can then reference with `\pageref` which gives me the correct page number. For the margin add `marginpar=1.5cm` to the geometry setting

Comment: It's not obvious to place the long texte below the title Figure 1

Comment: For the number of the page, the `changepage` package is perhaps enough ? but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

To answer part of my own bounty, I found a solution with `tcolorbox`.

Happy to receive feedback to improve it.

Would be interested in having a solution with new `tabularray`
(I could not change the text in the bounty).

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,raster,xparse}

\usepackage{geometry} 

\geometry{
    paper = a4paper,
    headheight = 14.1pt,
    left = 22.00mm, % left margin
    textwidth = 128mm, % main text block
    marginparsep = 4.0mm, % gutter 
    marginparwidth = 46.0mm % width of margin notes
}

\usepackage[
labelfont=sf,
hypcap=false,
format=hang,
%width=0.8\textwidth
]{caption}

\def\fullPage{\dimexpr \marginparwidth+\marginparsep+\textwidth\relax}

\newcommand{\testG}[4][] 
{
\tcbsidebyside[
    enhanced,   
    bicolor,
    before skip = 15pt,
    after skip = 15pt,
    coltext = orange!20!brown,
    toggle enlargement = evenpage, 
    grow to right by = \marginparwidth+\marginparsep, 
    sidebyside align = bottom,
    sidebyside gap = 2mm,
    colframe = gray!20,
    colframe = white,
    drop lifted shadow,
    segmentation style = {
        double = white,
        draw = white,
        double distance = 3pt,
        solid},
    if odd page = {
        sidebyside switch,
        lefthand width = \textwidth-0.5\marginparwidth, 
        colback = gray!5,
        colbacklower = gray!10,
    }%
    {%
    righthand width = \textwidth-0.5\marginparwidth,
    colback = gray!5,
    colbacklower = gray!10,
    before lower app = \centering,
    },
    boxrule = .5mm, 
    boxsep = 1mm, 
    left = 2pt,
    right = 4pt, 
    sidebyside gap = 1cm, 
    left skip = -1cm,
]{%
\captionof{figure}{#3}
    #4 % Some comments          
    }{%
\includegraphics[width = \textwidth,keepaspectratio]{#2}
}
            
}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

                                            
\testG
{example-image-a}
{\lipsum[1][1]}
{\lipsum[1][1-3]}

                        
\newpage                        
                        
\testG
{example-image-b}
{\lipsum[2][1]}
{\lipsum[2]}


\end{document}
```